# How to have A to Z as a variable

Tags: c++, arduino

I am so new to programming and I think this is a stupid question, but is it even possible to have a char like this:
char value = 'a', 'b', 'c', ... 'x', 'y', 'z'

and then if user input was anything other than A to Z , do something..

Like I have it here, the program sends a character to the Serial and if user enters any key it changes,,but i want to limit the user to a to z

```
char value; 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  value = 'a';
}

void loop()
{

  Serial.println(value);
  delay(1000);



  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  { 
       value = Serial.read();    
    Serial.println(value);
  }

}
```

Comment: You can't limit the user without taking out his keyboard buttons. What you can do is to check the input after it is received.

Comment: *is it even possible to have a char like this: char value = 'a', 'b', 'c', ... 'x', 'y', 'z'*
A character, no, but you have basically just described a string. This is overkill. Consider using [the `isalpha` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate user input and only allow 'a'-'z' or 'A'-'Z', you can do:

```
char some_user_val
if(('a' <= some_user_val && some_user_val <= 'z') || 
   ('A' <= some_user_val && some_user_val <= 'Z') {
    //Input was validated!!
} else {
    //Bad input
}
```

Comment: That assumes alphabet letters are consecutively coded. Better to use `isalpha`. Short and sweet.

Comment: This will fail for EBCDIC, although I doubt ardruino is going to use that.  Should still probably have a warning though.

Comment: Use `std::transform` to convert the text string to lower case so that only one comparison is necessary.

Comment: You could use a `const std::string` and assign it with all the valid character values.  Search this string.  If not in the string, the input value is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer would not work, check comments.**

<del>Would it not be possible to check this value after its already entered? You could do something like this, albeit with a more elegant execution.</del>

```
char value;
void setup() 
{ 
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    value = 'a';
}
void loop()
{ 
      Serial.println(value);
      delay(1000);
      if (Serial.available() > 0 && Serial.read().isalpha() != 0;) 
     { 
          value = Serial.read();
          Serial.println(value); 
     }
}
```

Comment: You are reading the value twice in the loop. The value printed is not the same as the one that was checked.

Comment: Ah, I assumed the read() function would return the same value in the same iteration of the loop.

Comment: `Serial.read` knows nothing about any loop that it is being called from.

Comment: Also the loop will print the last received character over and over again

Comment: Now this is the point where you should take your answer down for maintenance to avoid downvotes.

Comment: I'll leave it up, because the discussion is valuable, but I'll edit accordingly.